# C# parse elements of an HTTP POST response object from a string

Tags: c#, http

I have a set of files, each of which contain the full text of a series of HTTP POST responses.  A number of these contain binary objects (e.g. images or PDFs).  I've been trying to use regexes to extract the binary objects, but I can't seem to get it correctly.    The HTTPListener class (and associated classes) all seem to require an active connection, i.e. parsing a real time request response pair, which I don't have. Is there a good library out there which can parse a file (or a string) as an HTTP response?  If not, can anyone think of a better method for doing this than regex?

Thanks,
Rik

Comment: When you say "the full text" - if these are binary responses, they won't *be* text, other than the headers. Do you mean they're the complete responses, untouched?

Comment: Yes, the files are what you would get when you dump an HTTP POST response to file, so in the case of images, the headers are text and the binary object is a massive load of gobbledegook.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily write your own Parser which does the following:

1. Reads the Response file line by line
2. Till the line Content Length, which specifies the number of bytes in Payload
3. Read the payload as binary
4. Image class has an overload which creates an image from a Stream. This way you can verify whether your result images matches the original image.

Regards